# Real ViewModel with Composable Injected by Hilt in Instrumentation Test Zero Argument Constructor

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-testing, dagger-hilt

I want to have the real `ViewModel` injected into my composable. [This question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67337444/507313) is stating how to mock the injected view model which is not what I want.

My composable is receiving the view model like this:

`fun YourDetailsScreen(viewModel: YourDetailsViewModel = viewModel()) {`

The `viewModel()` method is the inline function provided by the `androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose` package.

As far as I'm aware, I have implemented the custom test runner, my instrumentation test is configured correctly with the `@HiltAndroidTest` and the `HiltAndroidRule` wrapping my `composeTestRule` like so:

```kotlin
@get:Rule
val rule: RuleChain = RuleChain.outerRule(hiltAndroidRule)
   .around(composeTestRule)
```

When I launch my composable, I get the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.zzz.feature.onboarding.registration.yourdetails.YourDetailsViewModel> has no zero argument constructor

Here is my `ViewModel`'s constructor.

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class YourDetailsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val isFirstNameValidUseCase: IsFirstNameValidUseCase,
    private val isLastNameValidUseCase: IsLastNameValidUseCase,
    private val isPhoneNumberValidUseCase: IsPhoneNumberValidUseCase
) : ViewModel()
```

Everything is injected fine when running the app, I just can't get it to work in my android tests!

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue! Did you find a solution for this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

After some hours of debugging, found the issue.

Basically, the main problem was that I was using `createComposeRule()` instead of `createAndroidComposeRule<MyActivity>()`, so the `HiltViewModelFactory` was not used.

After I started using `createAndroidComposeRule<MyActivity>()` as follow, my test started running:

```kotlin
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@HiltAndroidTest
class MyScreenTest  {

    val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MyActivity>()

    @get:Rule
    val rule: RuleChain = RuleChain.outerRule(hiltRule)
        .around(composeTestRule)

    // Tests....
}
```

(`MyActivity` must be annotated with `@AndroidEntryPoint`)

Comment: I guess the best option here would be to create a new TestActivity class with the annotation but no `setContent` so you can test whatever composable you want.